# Can't send a message in chat app with Sockets?

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, websocket

i'm trying to send a message through my app, but i always get this error in heroku. Here's the error:

[image]

and here is the api code: https://github.com/devslopes-learn/mac-chat-api

the snippet of the api code:

```
    client.on('newMessage', function(messageBody, userId, channelId, userName, userAvatar, userAvatarColor) {
    //Create message

    console.log(messageBody);

    let newMessage = new Message({
    messageBody: messageBody,
    userId: userId,
    channelId: channelId,
    userName: userName,
    userAvatar: userAvatar,
    userAvatarColor: userAvatarColor
  });
    //Save it to database
    newMessage.save(function(msg){
      //Send message to those connected in the room
      console.log('new message sent');

      io.emit("messageCreated",  newMessage.messageBody, newMessage.userId, newMessage.channelId, newMessage.userName, newMessage.userAvatar, newMessage.userAvatarColor, newMessage.id, newMessage.timeStamp);
    });
  });
```